# How to display time in terminal instead of username@hostname?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

In Ubuntu terminal you see:

```
someone@workstation:
```

as the prefix of each line. Is it possible to have the time displayed on each line?

```
[current time]someone@workstation:
```

The time will keep changing till I type "enter" such that the time info can be kept for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Ubuntu terminal you see [this] as the prefix of each line.

It's not the terminal that does that.  It is the *shell*.  What is displayed is the *shell prompt*.  And some shells have all sorts of wacky things that can be done in prompts.

In the Z Shell, for example, achieving what you want is simple:

```
TRAPALRM() { zle reset-prompt ; }
PS1='[%*] %n@%m:'
TMOUT=1
```

However, I suspect that what would be far more useful to you in the long run is the Z Shell's options for storing timestamps in the command history and displaying the command history with timestamps:

```
setopt extended_history
history -i
```

Or the Bourne Again shell's mechanism:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

### Further reading

- ["Parameters used by the shell"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell).  *Parameters*.  Z Shell Reference manual.
- ["Trap functions"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Trap-Functions).   *Functions*.  Z Shell Reference manual.
- ["Date and time"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Date-and-time). *Prompt Expansion*. Z Shell Reference manual.
- ["History"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History). *Options*. Z Shell Reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Run this -

```
PS1='\t:\u@\h:\w$ '
```

The terminal will now look like this

```
21:06:09:user@host:/etc$
```

That will turn the prompt into what you want.
If you want that permanently, put that line into `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I think the question is about having the time when the user presses enter to run the command, not the time the last command finished and returned to the prompt. I'm not aware of a method to do that in pure bash, but softwares like screen may help.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. In that case I don't know of any other way to do it apart from getting the user to hit enter before typing in any command to at least get the most recent time.

Comment: cool,how to make the time keep chaning ,so i know what time it is

Comment: There isn't really a way to do that AFAIK.